# Lost access to sudo on Mac. Want to regain access

Tags: macos, mac, sudo

I don't know what came in my mind that I just typed this in my shell:

```
sudo chmod 700 /usr/bin/sudo
```

and then also entered my password. The above command ran and I lost control over `sudo`.
`sudo` is owned by `root`. I am not the `root` user. My username is `aditya`.

Previously sudo had a permission of `711`. That means I could execute it being a non-root user. But now, I have lost control.

When I try to access `sudo` from my shell, I get:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied
```

Is there any way I can re-gain access to `sudo` without having to re-install my OS or call some engineer to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use `pkgutil` to list the installer information for sudo.

```
pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/sudo
```

Note the `mode` which is the permissions in `octal notation` for the file.

Shutdown your computer and then start the computer holding down the command key and the "s" key. You are booting the computer into single user mode.

At the prompt force check the file system with the command

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
```

then mount the file system read write

```
/sbin/mount -uw /
```

Now change the permissions on sudo

```
chmod 4511 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Then reboot the computer

```
reboot
```